# Using differentiation to find the power series for $x/(1+2x)^2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

So I am not sure how to go about this problem: finding the series representation of

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{(1+2x)^2}$$

I used $1/(1+2x)$ and created the power series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2x)^n = \frac{1}{1+2x}$$

and differentiated both sides. My derivative was

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(-1)^{n+1}(2x)^n = \frac{-2}{(1+2x)^2}$$

I found that I needed to multiply my power series by $-x/2$ in order for the power series to be equivalent to $x/(1+2x)^2$. What I don't understand is why this is wrong. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, how I would approach this:**

You'll want to start the geometric series, $|x| < 1$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, and then multiply both sides by $x$. You will obtain

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Replace $x$ with $-2x$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-2x)^n = \frac{-2x}{(1+2x)^2}$$

Multiply both sides by $-1/2$:

$$- \frac 1 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-2x)^n = \frac{x}{(1+2x)^2}$$

You can bring the $-1/2$ into the summation since $(-2x)^n = (-1)^n 2^n x^n$, causing some simplification:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-1)^{n+1} 2^{n-1} x^n= \frac{x}{(1+2x)^2}$$

Of course, $(-1)^{n+1} = (-1)^{n-1}$, so for a slightly cleaner-looking final answer, you can use that fact to recombine the $-1$ and $2$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-2)^{n-1} x^n= \frac{x}{(1+2x)^2}$$

---

**Your work, and where your error seems to arise:**

You begin by claiming, via the geometric series,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2x)^n = \frac{1}{1+2x}$$

Differentiating with respect to $x$ on both sides, you should get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2)n(-2x)^{n-1} = \frac{-2}{(1+2x)^2}$$

The summation simplifies a bit to

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2)n(-2x)^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-2)^n x^{n-1}$$

which doesn't at all seem like the result you claimed of

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(-1)^{n+1} (2x)^n$$

So I assume a calculation error arises here.

Comment: Hey, in the second step where you differentiated both sides, I noticed how you said the derivative of x^n was nx^n with respect to x but it didn't seem like you dropped the power down by 1. Is this a mistake? Assuming that it's a mistake, when you plugged in -2x for x and divided both sides by -1/2, will the power series of n(-2x)^(n-1) be separated into (-2)^(n-2)x^(n-1)? Lastly, I just wanted to note that I plugged in (n+1) for each n just so that the series will not have a term that starts with 0.

Comment: "Hey, in the second step where you differentiated both sides, I noticed how you said the derivative of x^n was nx^n with respect to x but it didn't seem like you dropped the power down by 1. Is this a mistake" -- As stated, I also multiplied by $x$ on both sides, which negates the dropping down of the power.

Comment: "Lastly, I just wanted to note that I plugged in (n+1) for each n just so that the series will not have a term that starts with 0" -- Did you reindex your summation properly, or did you only change the coefficient to $n+1$?

Comment: I couldn't change the index of my summation because WebAssign already set the initial index to 0. So the only thing I could do was replace each occurrence of n with n+1. So I changed the coefficient n to n+1, changed (-1)^n to (-1)^(n+1), and changed (2x)^n-1 to (2x)^n.

Answer (score -1):

$\frac{1}{1+2x} = \sum _0^{inf} \left(-2x \right )^n$

$-\frac{2}{\left ( 1+2x \right )^2} = \sum _1^{inf}{n \times \left( -2\right )^n \times x^{n-1}}=\sum _0^{inf}{\left( n+1\right ) \times \left( -2\right )^{n+1} \times x^{n}}$